# TexShop must not compile if one of the child files is missing

Tags: compiling, include

I am using TexShop v3.81 on Mac. In a root file, I include many subfiles (child or include files). On the last occasion I accidentally deleted one of the child file and compiled the root file, but it ran well. However, I object to this behavior; the TexShop must show an error, saying `\include{file name}`is missing. This will help me accidentally missing one of the files. I do not know if there is some kind of setting to do this. Pl. help.

Comment: TeXShop is not compiling your file. Rather, it's passing your file to your TeX distribution to compile. You should examine the Console output for errors and warnings after typesetting.

Comment: It is not clear what you object to, if you use `\input` then a missing file is an error and Tex will stop with an error message. If you use `\include` then it is a warning on the console and in the log.

Comment: I use \include. There is no warning/error flag given by the console. The root file skips the missing file and gives the output without publishing it. What I want is that the TeX distribution must NOT compile and the console must show error.

Comment: there is a warning:  console will say `No file ....` It is usually up to the language to determine what is an error and what is not, would you object to a C compiler not giving an error message on a valid input?

Comment: Thank you, David. Yes, I noticed that the compiler does show an error message, but it gives the output too. Since I do not look at the console if the output is valid I miss it. Is there any way to what I want? i.e. "show compilation error' if any of the files is missing. Even do not give vaild output! :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine `\include` to check that the file exists and if not terminate processing:

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\OldInclude\include
\renewcommand*{\include}[1]{%
\IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \OldInclude{#1}%
}{%
    \typeout{Error: Missing file: #1}
    \ExitDueToUndefinedControlSequence
}%
}

\begin{document}


some text

\include{zzzzz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: excellent choice of file name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yep, much better than your choice!

Answer (score 2):

Missing files are an error for `\input` but for `\include` there is no error but a message is sent to the console and the log file warning that the file is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{zzzzzzz}

\end{document}
```

produces terminal output of

```
No file zzzzzzz.tex.
```