# How to make \InputIfFileExists force end the compilation with a descriptive error message when the file is missing?

Tags: errors, input, external-files

The following gives me a message saying the `Process exited normally` with a corrupted output PDF file despite the absence of any file called `dummy`.

So, I need to have a compilation-halting error with a message about the missing input file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \InputIfFileExists{dummy}{}{}
\end{document}
```

---

Why can't I get the intended following message in the log file?

> Error: Missing file: dummy

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \InputIfFileExists{dummy}{}{%
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377312/2288
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383190/2288
        \typeout{Error: Missing file: #1}
        \ExitDueToUndefinedControlSequence
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should get no error from that, please show the complete log file. (I get no error with texlive 2020 pdflatex)

Comment: the answer to the question though would be to use `\input` instead of `\InputIfFileExists` as `\input` will give an error for a missing file, the point of `\InputIfFileExists` is exactly to avoid the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It will be even worse; `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \input{dummy}
\end{document}` doesn't stop when building with `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -file-line-error -halt-on-error "filemissing".tex`

Comment: for the version in the comment you could use `-interaction=nonstopmode`  instead of `\halt-on-error` but you have still provided no log for the version in the question. That should run to completion with no error at all.

Comment: The version in question didn't stop. I had to hit `stop` button of texstudio.

Comment: that is really weird. as I say show the log file, that should not happen. It should finish cleanly (with no pdf output)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, it stops now :D. Here it is https://pastebin.com/7ranuvvL

Comment: That looks as expected:-) No error or corrupted PDF, just `warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Before you asked for the log, it didn't stop but no one would believe me `:D`

Comment: OK I will take credit for fixing your document, then we can all agree it's fixed now. and egreg gets his 15 points and a green tick, so we are all happy.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle His `expl3` solution is great, but I would like to have the solution in the old school way with typing the missing file name in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thereisnosuchfile}{%
  \@latex@error{No file to input}{The file you asked for doesn't exist}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\InputIfFileExists{dummy}{}{\thereisnosuchfile}

\input{dummy}

\end{document}
```

What's the difference? In the first case there is no request for another file name. On the other hand, in the second case, just hitting return would exit from the loop by inputting the empty `.tex` file.

```
! LaTeX Error: No file to input.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 ...tIfFileExists{dummy}{}{\thereisnosuchfile}
                                                  
? 

! LaTeX Error: File `dummy.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: <<hit return>>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex File ignored)
```

If you add `\stop` at the end of the definition of `\thereisnosuchfile`, the LaTeX run would stop after hitting return.

An `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\saferinput}{m}
 {
  \file_if_exist_input:nF { #1 } { \msg_error:nnn { diaa } { no-file } { #1 } }
 }
\msg_new:nnnn { diaa } { no-file }
 { No~file~'#1' }
 { The~file~'#1'~you~asked~for~does~not~exist }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\saferinput{dummy}

\end{document}
```

Console output

```
! Package diaa Error: No file 'dummy'

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 \saferinput{dummy}
                       
? h

The file 'dummy' you asked for does not exist

?
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you could take a look at my question update and explain why I can't the find that message in the log file. Thanks

Comment: @Diaa You can't use `#1` in that place.

Comment: I just followed this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383190/2288. If you can correct it, kindly do.

Comment: @Diaa No, that's a different situation. You cannot refer to the first argument to `\InputIfFileExists` in the third argument by `#1`; that code is defining a new command where the file name is passed as argument.

Comment: I understand. Is there a reason why I get `Package diaa Error: No file 'dummy'` in the log file without the second sentence `The file 'dummy' you asked for does not exist`?

Comment: @Diaa That only pops out if you hit `h` at the error prompt.

Comment: Can the first solution be edited to pass the missing file name to `\thereisnosuchfile` to show up in the log file? I need it to show up in the first message `No file to input` since I am using an editor where I can't press buttons after the error.

Comment: @Diaa What's the reason in insisting to use `\InputIfFileExists` in the document? It's not thought to be used in the document! Define `\saferinput` in those terms and you can pass the argument.