# TikZ/external: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-external, externalize

Why do I get this error of `missing \begin{document}` in the log file `therect.log` of the externally built image `threct.pdf`?

P.S. I am sorry for not fully cleaning the code of repeated package loading and unnecessary packages.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{export}{adjustbox}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{rect.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em,blue]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle node{Diaa} (4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[
addpoints,
%answers
]{exam}

\usepackage{catchfile,lipsum,graphbox,array,ragged2e,booktabs,fmtcount,multicol,multirow,calc,tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1562#a1814
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@external@watch@store@aux#1#2{%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\xdef\noexpand\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/watch/stored/#1\string\endcsname{#2}}}%
\def\tikz@external@watch@get@from@aux#1#2{%
    \ifcsname pgfk@/tikz/external/watch/stored/#1\endcsname
    \edef#2{\csname pgfk@/tikz/external/watch/stored/#1\endcsname}%
    \else
    \edef#2{0}%
    \fi}
\tikzset{external/watch/.cd,store/.code 2 args={%
        \tikz@external@watch@store@aux{#1}{#2}},
    get/.code 2 args={\tikz@external@watch@get@from@aux{#1}{#2}},
    font size/.code={\tikzset{external/watch/get={font size}{\pgfutil@tempa},
            external/watch/store={font size}{\f@size}}%
        \unless\ifnum\pgfutil@tempa=\f@size
        \tikzset{/tikz/external/force remake}%
        \fi
}}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{external}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482560/2288
% https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=1605&id=85129#c85129
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576077/2288
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputtikz}{ m m }{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}{%
        \tikzset{external/export=true}%
        \tikzsetnextfilename{#2}%
        \input{#1}%
        \tikzset{external/export=false}%
    }{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383190/2288
        \typeout{Error: Missing file: #1}
        \ExitDueToUndefinedControlSequence%
    }%
}

\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, calc, positioning, patterns, decorations, decorations.markings, quotes, fpu, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing}

% for DC Motor Circuit Drawing
\tikzset{rotarrow/.pic={
        \draw[thin,->] (-0.2,-0.2)  to [out=-60,in=60, looseness=4] ++(0,0.4) node [above=1mm] {\tikzpictext};
    },
}


\usepackage[xparse,breakable,raster,skins]{tcolorbox}% xparse,breakable
\tcbset{shield externalize}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331068/2288
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}%
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
% https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=1605&id=85129#c85129
\tikzset{external/.cd, 
    watch/font size, 
    export = false,
}


\inputtikz{rect.tikz}{therect}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are loading in your example more than 40 packages, and most of them are probably unrelated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When I reduced my document before, I couldn't manage to get the error reproduced. So, I started with this messy version hoping to reduce it properly without losing the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please, check my updated version.

Comment: sorry it is not reasonable to post that much obscure code and ask people to run with `--shell-escape`  shell escape is disabled for a reason. (that said if someone does trust you enough to run the posted example, it runs without error)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No problem. I will delete the whole question.

Comment: you (again!!) have not provided the log showing the error that you got. I get no error from this example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sparing the log . I just showed the error. Anyway, here it is that of `therect` https://pastebin.com/Zz1BXHJ2 which has  the `missing begin{document}`. And this is of the main file https://pastebin.com/wVAWb6Cu

Comment: why use external links? The question is archived forever and your pastebin links are probably not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't prefer making the question that long. Anyway, I will put them in the question itself.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found out the problem and don't know if I should delete the question or keep it. The main cause was having a space in the main file, and I know how much you hate spaces `XD`. However, is there any clue in the log file leads me to true the criminal?

Comment: I was just coming back to post https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129  as I saw the space in your log, once I saw your comment above

Comment: let me see if I can reproduce with a space, although it may be windows specific

Comment: OK I can reproduce if there is a space in the filename, error not clear from the log but as I comment above just seeing the filename in your log would be enough for me to suggest the fix of not having a space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The space here was accidental not intentional, and if you are not such texpert, you take a lot of time like me. Please, advise, should I delete, close, answer the question?

Comment: actually I think it is worth answering as I have to admit the error message here is completely impossible to understand the guess of trying it without a space in the name comes from experience not anything in the log. Others may be helped to see that, you could self answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is a result of having a space in the file name of the main document.

Furthermore, when dealing with the external library of `tikz` spaces are so notorious and explosive (when used in the names of `main file`,`\tikzsetnextfilename`, `*.tikz` file) and give completely incomprehensible errors as the one in my question.